# Can I add a Unique key on table creation in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to translate a collection of MySQL functions to SQL, and I'm having issues with a `UNIQUE KEY` issue:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table testform
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `testform` (
    `FormId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `TTId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `TestName` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`FormId`),
    UNIQUE KEY `TF_Composite` (`TTId`, `TestName`));
```

When I try and test this in SQLFiddle, it's giving me the error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'KEY'.

I have tried searching for this, but so far all I have come up with is "Unique *Constraints*". Is there a difference between a "Key" and a "Constraint" in SQL? And if so, how can I add this in the table creation statement?

Comment: to my understanding the problem is the word KEY with UNIQUE, i think you just need UNIQUE

Comment: Any reason you tagged SQL Server?

Comment: @Memor-X I removed the `KEY`, but now it's saying *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TF_Composite'"*

Comment: @DavidG because that's the database that I am trying to translate this for? MS SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
CREATE TABLE testform (
    FormId INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TTId INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    TestName VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (FormId),
    CONSTRAINT TF_Composite UNIQUE (TTId,TestName));
```

[More Details..](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: The ` do not work in SQL Server 2014 with default SET statements.  No such thing as INT(11) or AUTO_INCREMENT.  Down voting!

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA Again, He's basically just copied my query and addressed the `UNIQUE` constraint issue. If you want to nit-pick, even the '\`' characters cause issues in SQL Server!

Comment: My intention to correct the unique constraint , so did not check for grave accent ( ` ).
Yes,grave accent ( ` ) wont work , thanks CRAFTY DBA.

Comment: ROFLOL - If you want to give the syntax above as a solution, go for it.  However, there are multiple issues with the statement.  I try not only to address the UNIQUE constraint issue but give the user a solution that works and has been tested.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is all messed up.  Please look at books on-line (MSDN).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

The sample code below create a table in tempdb.  This table automatically gets destroyed when the service is restarted.

```
-- Just a example, throw away after reboot
USE [tempdb]
GO

-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE DBO.TESTFORM 
(
    FORM_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    TT_ID INT NULL,
    TEST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_FORM_ID PRIMARY KEY (FORM_ID),
    CONSTRAINT UN_COMPOSIT UNIQUE (TT_ID, TEST_NAME)
);

-- Seventies Band
INSERT INTO TEMPDB.DBO.TESTFORM VALUES (1, 'John');
INSERT INTO TEMPDB.DBO.TESTFORM VALUES (2, 'Paul');
INSERT INTO TEMPDB.DBO.TESTFORM VALUES (3, 'Mary');
GO

-- Show data
SELECT * FROM  TEMPDB.DBO.TESTFORM 
GO
```

The image below shows the data in this table.

[image]

Comment: Hi, yes I realise there are a few other issue with this - this is primarily the syntax taken from the MySQL query. My main concern was to do with the `UNIQUE KEY` syntax, as I had never come across it before in SQL.

Comment: No worries.  Try the sample above in Management Studio 2014.  It works!  I tested it.  Enjoy SQL Server!

Comment: Also, you want to name your constraints in most cases.  Otherwise, you get weird names.  Except to rule is code that generates temporary tables.  Since all tables are in [tempdb], name collisions occur.

Answer (score 0):

For Better Understanding about Primary and Unique you can refer below page.
[Primary and Unique Key Creation](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/V2bS260912-Difference-between-Primary-Key-and-Unique-Key.html)

Comment: Ok, I do understand the difference between these - it's pretty much the same as in MySQL - but how do I declare this? What's the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL Database

```
CREATE TABLE `phone` (
`id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`country` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`area` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`number` DECIMAL(8,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`extension` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `ix_phone` (`country`, `area`, `number`, `extension`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

For alter Table :

`ALTER TABLE`phone
 `ADD UNIQUE INDEX`ix_phone`(`country`,`area`,`number`,`extension`);`